# Generic type for react ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a library function that returns a ref which needs to be passed to some element. The library doesn't care which type of element it is, so I'd like to type it as `React.Ref<HTMLElement>`.

The problem is, assignment rule for refs is backwards. `Ref<HTMLElement>` can't be passed to a div element or any other element for that matter.

If I make the library return `Ref<HTMLDivElement>` then it can't be applied to any other element type.

What's the correct pattern for that, and why is react ref typed that way?

Answer (score 1):

Try to type it like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, RefObject } from 'react';

type UseYo<T extends HTMLElement> = {
  ref: RefObject<T>;
};

function useYo<T extends HTMLElement>(): UseYo<T>{
  const ref = useRef<T>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) {
      return;
    }
    // do something with ref
  }, [])

  return { ref };
}

function MyComponent() {
  const { ref } = useYo<HTMLDivElement>();

  return (
    <div ref={ref}></div>
  );
}
```

[See it on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSyZ29A8gEYBWV8AvnGVBCDgByKKgxCA3ACgpMAJ5gkcAKrEAmhAA8AFThIAHjCQA7ACaE4ACW0BZADIkANkhAmYAPjgBeXFLhxRMgAuRCQyVg4MHXdpLmkpA0hYOFMwlHxHeDJ8YwxgCGMCdS1dAyMzC2t7Jxc3dwAKAEoQ1SQNaJw-ODQCwnhA7yK6MOj64wzHRvj-WnJKDHqm709O-39gMjh6gEJAgDo0fChRYxhG3zW10Rgj42lLri7-AHpnlIg4QgEkGAALYGMAHM4AB3YB-AJhLpcbAAbQAuo0ZP5rrdcJDNnEpI8pNlcjB8oUbHIAMICSDGNxLVbdXrwPADHg+WjtKp2AAiwAAbjVXKcGlNkZCblBCvUnnBNKZuRivDhAlx3JpntKue4uoKuEA)

Comment: Sure, I could pass the type through, but it seems counter productive as the function doesn't need to know the type, it just needs any HTML element :(

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, this is a question of [covariance and contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/25507).

To oversimplify, covariance means that you can substitute an instance of a more specific type when passing a parameter.

```js
function doSomething(el: HTMLElement) { /* ... */ }

const myDiv: HTMLDivElement;
doSomething(myDiv); // ok, myDiv is an HTMLELement
```

However, function parameters are contravariant:

```js
function doSomething(callback: (el: HTMLElement) => void) { /* ... */ }

const myCallback: (el: HTMLDivElement) => void;
doSomething(myCallback); // No good!
// myCallback may be called with *any* HTMLElement, but it only says it takes divs
```

Refs are more like the function parameters example. The type system doesn't "know" that a ref is an output-only parameter; in actuality, it's more like the following:

```js
interface Ref<T> { current: T };

function Div(ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>);

const myRef: Ref<HTMLElement>;
Div({ref: myRef}); // No good!
// Div says it only takes divs, but ref.current may be *any* HTMLElement
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of a clean solution within TypeScript's type system. You can resort to typecasts:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const myRef = useRefFromMyLibrary();
  return <div ref={myRef as Ref<HTMLDivElement>} />;
}
```

Or use generics, as in [@moonwave99's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78049918/25507).

Comment: Pretty much, refs are typed incorrectly in react (which is likely a Typescript limitation). You can pass a more specific ref to a function that expects a less specific one, when it should be the other way around. I.e. you can pass a Div ref to a function that expects a generic Element ref, that function sets the current field to any HTML element and the calling function will think that it contains a Div. But logically correct substitution is considered an error. If all refs were function refs, this wouldn't be a problem, but this obviously is much less convenient.

Comment: I think one simple solution would be making a function wrapper for refs, since functions are contravariant by default.